# How to get last modified date of file provided by ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android

Currently I have the following piece of code that allows a user to select an image

```
Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
chooserIntent.setType("image/*");
chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(chooserIntent, "Select a picture");
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SOME_INTEGER_REQUEST_CODE);
```

This returns something along the lines of this

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A57
```

How do I get the last modified time?

```
File fileObject   = new File("content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A57");
Long fileModified = fileObject.lastModified();
```

Doing this only gives me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"`

Comment: Of course you cannot use the File class. You should use getContentResolver().query(uri,...);

Comment: @greenapps you could elaborate more your answer